# Query on usage of mean value theorem when function is only continuous at a single point

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I refer to a previous question: 
 [Directional Derivative Existence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789890/directional-derivative-existence-question)
and the answer given.

I like his answer, however, I don't understand why we can use the Mean Value Theorem in that scenario.

Basically my concern is that it is only given that $f_x$ is continuous at a single point $(p,q)$, and $f_x$ exists at $(p,q)$. For the Mean Value Theorem, I believe we need continuity on a closed interval and differentiability on an open interval?

Answer (score 2):

The Mean Value Theorem needs only that $f$ be continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and that the limit in the definition of the (directional) derivative of $f$ exists in $(a,b)$, either as a finite real number or as $\pm \infty$. Notice that when the limit is finite, that limit **is** the derivative.

In particular, since you say $f_x$ is continuous at $(p,q)$, it is implied that $f_x$ (and hence the aforementioned limit) exists in a neighborhood of $(p,q)$. Hence, if $f$ is continuous near $(p,q)$ everything should be good.

Can you see that $f$ is continuous near $(p,q)$?

Comment: How do I see $f$ is continuous near $(p,q)$? I know that differentiability implies continuity for single variable case. However I am having difficulty seeing it here.

Comment: Since you're applying the MVT only with respect to the $x$ variable, you need only continuity with respect to it.