# Example of functions where limits don't commute

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

Can we have a function $f(h,k)$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{k\to 0}f(h,k)\neq \lim_{k\to 0}\lim_{h\to 0}f(h,k)?$$

Comment: $f(h,\,k) = \frac{h^{2} - k^{2}}{h^{2} + k^{2}}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $$f(x,y)=\frac {x-y}{x+y}\quad(x+y\neq0).$$You can extend the domain to $\Bbb R^2$ by defining $f(x,y)=0$ when $x+y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Moore-Osgood theorem deals with interchange iterated limits like this, See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit) and [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Moore-Osgood_Theorem)

Simple counter example from the wiki:

$$ \lim_{x,y \to 0,0} f(x,y) = \lim_{x \to 0 } \lim_{ y \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2 +y^2}$$

More detailed discussion about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51308/688539)

Comment: p.s: I have no idea about the technicalities of the theorem because my knowledge of it is from a time where I found a limit interchanging problem xD

Comment: @mithusengupta123: For some strong counterexamples and more refined theorems, see the two links given in my answer to [Functions continuous in each variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51308/13130) (my 5th Stack Exchange answer; the July 2011 date had me curious, so I checked with my earliest answers). This non-commutativity of limits was an especially motivating issue for many significant developments in the late 1800s and early 1900s (e.g. the [Baire category theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22baire+category%22), among other things).

Comment: Those papers are wayy beyond my current level but I have added that answer into mine :D

Comment: *wayy beyond my current level* --- I thought as much (I'm older is all), but I was thinking others might be interested (or you or the OP in time).