# Limit notation (for taking multiple limits at once)

Tags: functional-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, notation

This is probably a silly question, but I am interested in looking at limits of multi-variable functions, such as \begin{equation}\lim_{x_1\to\infty}\lim_{x_2\to\infty}\cdots\lim_{x_m\to\infty}f(x_1,\cdots,x_m).\end{equation}

Is it notationally acceptable to simply write the above as \begin{equation}\lim_{\substack{x_i\to\infty}\\i=1,\cdots,m}f(x_1,\cdots,x_m)?\end{equation}

This notation would be slightly less space-consuming which is why I thought it would be a good idea but I'm not sure if this is standard notation.

Comment: The problem is limits don't commute in general. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3904577) uses two $\to0$ limit operators rather than $m$ limits that $\to\infty$, but the principle is the same. So you need to clarify, e.g. with a statement that you're numbering the variables so $\lim_{\substack{x_i\to\infty}\\i=1,\cdots,m}$ means $\lim_{x_1\to\infty}\lim_{x_2\to\infty}\cdots\lim_{x_m\to\infty}$.

Comment: ((1)) You can not use it in general because the limit **might** depend on the order for the general class of functions ((2)) When you are considering a special class of functions where the order is immaterial , you **can & should** use the compact way to high-light that the order is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

The notation you suggest might be ambiguous, since the limits might not commute, i.e. we might have (in the case $m=2$ here)
$$
\lim_{x_1\to\infty}\lim_{x_2\to\infty}f(x_1,x_2)\neq\lim_{x_2\to\infty}\lim_{x_1\to\infty}f(x_1,x_2).
$$
To give an example, consider
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=\bigg(1+\frac{1}{x_1}\bigg)^{x_2},
$$
with $x_1,x_2>0$. Then
$$
\lim_{x_1\to\infty}\lim_{x_2\to\infty}f(x_1,x_2)=\infty\neq1=\lim_{x_2\to\infty}\lim_{x_1\to\infty}f(x_1,x_2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

This notation could lead to confusions. Some may think that  $$\lim_{\substack{x_i\to\infty\\i=1,2}}f(x_1,x_2)$$ means $$\lim_{x_1\to\infty} \lim_{x_2\to\infty} f(x_1,x_2)$$
while others could think it means
$$\lim_{x_2\to\infty} \lim_{x_1\to\infty} f(x_1,x_2)$$